# Why is my code giving me a memory error? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I am trying to create a mock item buy menu. I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me why my vector is returning -858993460 instead of the int value that I am trying to read into it through an array. I am trying to read it like an array and it is saying I have a memory issue. I am stuck.

Here are the related variables I have declared

```
string exit, storeChoice;
double balance = 10000;
bool store = true;
const int inv = 10;
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int Choice;
int iLimit[inv], categoryChoice;
vector<int> invVec;
```

Here is the line the error occurs on and the error popup on visual studio.
cout << invVec.at(iLimit[i]) << endl;
Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location

The following code is inside my main()

```
        if (categoryChoice == 1)
        {
            cin >> Choice;
            Choice >> iLimit[i];
            if (Choice != 0)
            {
                invVec.push_back(iLimit[i]);

                for (i = 0; inVec.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << invVec.at(i) << endl; 
                }
            
                Choice = 0;
            }
```

Comment: On which line? Does a debugger provide any insight?

Comment: Are you *sure* `invVec` has 9 entries? That seems like a huge assumption. I'd recommend: `for (auto&& item : invVec) { std::cout << item << std::endl; }` to print.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have not given us enough code to reproduce the error, and much of the code you've posted seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Hi there, I will simplify the code to show the error better.

I am trying to print a vector to the console that contains data I'm reading in from an array which reads in input from the user.

Afterwards I tried cout << invVec[i];
it returned "Vector subscript out of range" 

Severity Code Description 
Warning C6001 Using uninitialized memory 'iLimit'.

Comment: That latest code looks very wrong. Are you sure you don't mean cout << invVec.at(i) << endl;

Comment: @tadman I am trying to simulate an inventory system of 9 slots, I will try your suggestion though to see if it changes anything. Thank you for the response.

Comment: if, when they buy something, that item should fill up an inventory slot, (and the Choice number should be put in the inventory spot) then you don't need the second array (iLimit)  You could just push Choice directly into invVec, and then make sure than inVec.size() does not exceed 9.  This way the first item they buy would go into slot 0, the second into slot 1 etc.

Comment: @matt Yes! my apologies. That was what I had there before, I was trying different things and it got into my post.

I'm still getting an error thrown on that line which says : std::out_of_range at memory location

I am going to try your suggestion right now and get rid of the array.

Comment: Tip: Don't *assume* how many slots it has. Always respect whatever size it *actually* has. You can limit inventory, like refusing to `push_back()` if it's too "full", but that's a different responsibility and different code.

Comment: The code as it looks now should not get a memory error?

Comment: Quick answer for you (the variable is not ever assigned a value) to prove this initialization assign the value to 0 and you will find that it ends at 0. Meaning the assigning of the variable never happens. note if ```categoryChoice == 1``` problem is categoryChoice!=1 because it isn't initially assigned 1???? please share enough code for proper diagnosing.

Comment: Thanks all for comments. I appreciate all the information I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Choice >> iLimit[i];
```

This doesn't do what you think it does, I think you mean

```
iLimit[i] = Choice;
```

the >> operator has been overloaded for string types (and cin, cout etc) to copy the value from one to the other. But this is not the case for ints, where >> is the bitshift operator. it doesn't modify any of the operands but instead returns the result (which you are just disregarding), sort of like doing:

```
Choice + iLimit[i];
```

This means nothing is ever put in your iLimit array, and so its just full of garbage (such as -858993460 ), as such when you go

```
invVec.at(iLimit[i])
```

you are basically doing

```
invVec.at(-858993460)
```

Which is obviously not a valid index into your vector, therefore the memory error.

Comment: I just fixed it using that code you gave me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!  However you might find questions that go like this aren't looked upon kindly by some. We worked through your issue, with you updating the question quite a bit. Where as the site seems to primarily exist to create Q&As that are useful for *others* to view. Ask yourself if this question and its answers would now help others?

I don't want to discourage you from asking questions, just be aware in case this question gets deleted or something, that's probably why :)

Comment: That is good to know. I felt dumb after updating it twice, so I am going to make sure to get the question right on the first iteration next time.

I couldn't rest until I figured out why this code wasn't working, I am really happy with the amount of response I've gotten even with the messiness of the question.

I hope someone still finds this useful, I know I sure did!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because

```
cout << invVec.at(iLimit[i]) << endl; // Trying to display inventory.. Memory
```

iLimit[i] returns your item id, not the element's index

in your code earlier, you added to invVec

```
invVec.push_back(iLimit[i]);
```

But when you are accessing using .at(n), n must be the index and not the value

So in your case, you should change up your loop a little to become

```
for(i = 0;i < invVec.size();i ++) {
    cout << invVec.at(i) << endl; // Trying to display inventory.. Memory 

}
```

also, will be helpful to include some output from your console in future

Comment: Better to use an iterator-driven approach here unless an index is explicitly needed, but at least this respects the `size()`.

Comment: @tadman I used the code below that you gave me and it worked perfectly for my memory error issue that persisted even after it printed correctly... I am still wondering why/how this fixed that part of it.

 for (auto&& item : invVec)
                    {
                        cout << item << endl; 
                    }

Comment: You were accessing the vector *out of bounds* and getting an error because of it. That code cannot go out of bounds, it will only iterate over what exists. When you *assume* a vector has a certain size that's usually wrong. Even if correct initially, that could change over time, leading to difficult to track down bugs. You want to write code that can deal with change, hence: iterators.

Comment: @tadman You are truly great! Gratzi!! We have just learned about vectors & arrays last week, I am sure this will come in handy in the future.